# Update object property value base on another object property value failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Was trying to update property value of an array of object using es6 map. What's wrong with my logic?

```
this.state = {
      "fruits":[
        {"name":"banana","value":true},
        {"name":"watermelon","value":false},
        {"name":"lemon","value":false}
      ]
    }

const key = 'lemon';
const newFruitsData = this.state.fruits.map(obj => 
      obj.name === key ? obj.value = true : ''     
    )

console.log(newFruitsData)
```

Can't make up my react http://jsbin.com/jagononuwe/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Don't you need a `:` somewhere in `obj.name === key ? obj[key].value = true`?  And why are you setting `obj[key].value` instead of `obj.value`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel can't work too, http://jsbin.com/jagononuwe/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Well, you're mapping an object to one property of it or the empty string, so the setState blows away your state.

Comment: @MikeSamuel yeah I'm lost now, is there any lodash function that can simply update the property value base on the name property?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing ES6 [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `[Array.prototype.map]`

```
 // demonstrates how to use ES6 MAP - The Map object is a simple key/value    object. 

  var fruits= new Map();
  fruits.set('banana', true);
  fruits.set('apple', false);
  for (var [key, value] of fruits) {
   console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
  }
```

is different from the `Array.prototype.map` method  - this creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array. Click on the link provided above.

```
// to achieve what you are trying to do use `forEach` 

   this.state = {
    "fruits":[
    {"name":"banana","value":true},
    {"name":"watermelon","value":false},
    {"name":"lemon","value":false}
  ]
}

   const key = 'lemon';

   const newFruitsData = this.state.fruits.find(obj => {
        if (obj.name === key) {
              obj.value = false;
        }
  }); 

  const printNewData = () =>{
       this.state.fruits.forEach(obj => {
            console.log(`${obj.name} ${obj.value}`);
      });
   };

 printNewData();
```

Comment: how does that different? It's the same.

Comment: so the map that often been use in react is array map? not es6's map? but it used babel so I thought it's es6 map

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using .find for this type of operation.  Map will produce a new array for you.  Written in this way you would have to reassign a new state every time you update a state value.  Find would allow you (or other methods) even would allow you to specify which value you would like updated. Depending on the rest of the code, this might be more efficient.

```
this.state = {
  "fruits":[
    {"name":"banana","value":true},
    {"name":"watermelon","value":false},
    {"name":"lemon","value":false}
  ]
}

const key = 'lemon';
const newFruitsData = this.state.fruits.find(obj => {
  if (obj.name === key) obj.value = !obj.value
});

console.log(this.state)
```

Comment: I prefer lodash's find as it's faster. But I'm stuck here, need your help, http://jsbin.com/pujaducawa/1/edit?js,console,output

it doesn't have my existing object.

Comment: Hey @Melissa I updated it.  The clicking functionality works now.
http://jsbin.com/pujaducawa/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: I'm still seeing my code, u need to clone/save a copy.

Comment: derp.  I am still new at this. http://jsbin.com/qizefefeha/1/edit?js,console,output